# Validate Input only on blur or loose focus

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms, validation, jquery-form-validator

I am using - **victorjonsson/jQuery-Form-Validator**

URL: https://github.com/victorjonsson/jQuery-Form-Validator

I am validating a from, and using toggleDisabled feature.
Form validate the input every time I press a key even on tab to get the new field.
On tab both previous and new fields get validated.

Is this possible to validate the field only on blur, mean any property to attach.

Code I am using:

```
$.validate({ modules : 'security, toggleDisabled', disabledFormFilter : 'form.formcreateaccount', showErrorDialogs : true });
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the option `validateOnBlur: true`